# Start Android Application using Command Line

Tags: android, shell, command-line, adb

I am having trouble finding this specific answer and was hoping someone could help me.

I am trying to start an Android Application from the command line.  This would be an application that I did not develop that I downloaded from the Google Play Store.

I know there is a way to start an application from adb commands if you know the package name and such like this:

*adb shell
am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName*

When you did not develop the application, how do you know the package name or activity name?  Is there a way to find this information on the application?  Is there just a generic adb command to start up or run an application?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Check the url of the app in the Play Store ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to my question.  You can find the answer here:

https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/how-to-find-apppackage-and-appactivity-for-apk-file/#:~:text=1)%20Open%20command%20prompt.,devices%20attached%20to%20your%20computer.

1) Ensure adb is installed on your PC and the device is connected via adb
2) Type ‘adb shell’, to get in to the device.
3) Ensure the application you wish to retrieve information on is open
4) Type dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp’

I hope this helps someone in the future.